# vimscript: commands that work in mappings, but not in functions

Tags: function, vim, mapping

How can I rewrite these 2 commands, which work fine in a mapping, so that they will work in a function?

```
:if has_key(glos,@g)==1<cr>:let @j=eval('glos.'.@g)<cr>
```

The function concerned is executed by vim without comment, but @j remains unchanged, as if they had failed, but no message/error is generated.

Here is the complete code involved, the command that loads the dictionary, the function that does not work, and the mapping from that function that does.

```
" read the glossary into the dictionary, glos
let glos=eval(join(readfile("glossary.dict")))
" 2click item of interest and this will
" send image filepath to xv
" if item all-caps find same at start of its line
" If capitalized at eol find same at start of its line
" if all lower-case at eol find next occurrence of same
" look lower-case or capitalized word up in glossary.txt
" find _\d\+ (page no.) alone on its line in text
com! F call F()   
function! F()
normal "ayiw"cyE"by$
let @c=substitute(@c,"[,.?':;!]\+","","g")
if @c=~'images\/ss\d\d\d*'
  let @i='!display -geometry +0+0 '.@c.' &'
  pkill display
  @i
elseif @c==toupper(@c)
  let @n=search('^'.@c,'sw')
elseif @c!=@b
  let @f=3
  let @g=tolower(@c)
  while @f>0
    try
      let @j=eval('glos.'.@g)
    catch
      let @f=@f-1
      let @g=strpart(@g,0,strlen(@g)-1)
      continue
    endtry
    break
  endwh
  if @f>0
    let @h=substitute(@j," glosimgs.*",'','')
    if @h!=@j
       let @i='!xv -geometry +0+380 '.substitute(@j,'^.\{-}\( glosimgs.*\)$','\1','').' &'
      !pkill xv
      @i
    endif
    echo @h
  else
     echo 'No matching entry for '.@c
  endif
elseif @c=~'\u\l\+$'
  let @n=search('^'.@c,'sw')
 elseif @c=~'\l\+$'
  norm *
elseif @c=~'^_\w\+$'
    let @/='^'.@c.'$'
    norm nzz
endif
endfunction
map <silent> <2-LeftMouse> "ayiw"cyE"by$:let @c=substitute(@c,"[,.?':;!]\+","","g")<cr>:if @c=~'images\/ss\d\d\d*'<cr>:let @i='!display -geometry +0+0 '.@c.' &'<cr>:pkill display<cr>:@i<cr>:elseif @c==toupper(@c)<cr>:let @n=search('^'.@c,'sw')<cr>:elseif @c!=@b<cr>:let @f=3<cr>:let @g=tolower(@c)<cr>:while @f>0<cr>:try<cr>:let @j=eval('glos["'.@g.'"]')<cr>:catch<cr>:let @f=@f-1<cr>:let @g=strpart(@g,0,strlen(@g)-1)<cr>:continue<cr>:endtry<cr>:break<cr>:endwh<cr>:if @f>0<cr>:let @h=substitute(@j," glosimgs.*",'','')<cr>:if @h!=@j<cr>:let @i='!xv -geometry +0+380 '.substitute(@j,'^.\{-}\( glosimgs.*\)$','\1','').' &'<cr>:!pkill xv<cr>:@i<cr>:endif<cr><cr<cr>>:echo @h<cr>:else<cr>:echo 'No matching entry for '.@c<cr>:endif<cr>:elseif @c=~'\u\l\+$'<cr>:let @n=search('^'.@c,'sw')<cr>:elseif @c=~'\l\+$'<cr>:norm *<cr>:elseif @c=~'^_\w\+$'<cr>:let @/='^'.@c.'$'<cr>:norm nzz<cr>:endif<cr>
```

Comment: Can you post the the mapping? That fragment is not a valid expression. I'm not sure how your mapping works. (If it does at all)

Comment: Oh my... Sorry but I don't want to interpret everything here. As a first step it might help to use actual variables instead of registers `@[a-z]` is a register which your function probably shouldn't overwrite in the general case.  You might want to read `:help internal-variables` to understand how variables works. (Descriptive variable names are a good thing) As for your mapping I don't believe it actually works. I get a trailing characters error.

Comment: Never mind; if the mapping works for me but gives you an error our setups are different.  As this is a recurrent problem with vim (why else does it need so many methods to coerce balky functions to run, eval exe call and loading it in a register and using that as a command), I see the easiest option is to live with it, and write a mapping to flip long mappings into one command per line form and back again to make it easily readable for maintenance/debugging.  Thanks for your help

Comment: What are you trying to do? It might be easier to come up with a different solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, I should have written:
    :if has_key(**g:**glos,@g)==1:let @j=eval('**g:**glos.'.@g)

:h g: goes straight to the heart of the matter; in a function all references are local to that function, so references to any variable outside the function must be global, by prepending 'g:' to the variable name.  As I created the dictionary independent of the function, the function must reference it as a global item.

Of course, if you are not aware of 'g:', it is rather difficult to find that help reference, but that's a frequent problem using help.

And, of course, the ** surrounding g: aren't required, that's what this site gives you in lieu of bolded text, apparently.